# Plural or singular when comparing two different objects?

Tags: grammaticality

Should I use plural or singular when comparing two different objects? For example, I want to tell a friend that I have two clothes that are of different styles but have the same color.

> "The *colors* of shirt-A and shirt-B *are* blue."

or should I say,

> "The *color* of shirt-A and shirt-B *is* blue."

or maybe even the following?

> "The *colors* of both shirt-A and shirt-B *are* blue."
>   vs
>   "The *color* of both shirt-A and shirt-B *is* blue."

Answer (score 1):

By making reference to the colour *instance*, you don't need to explicitly mention that you are talking about the colour *property*.  Native English users would simply say:

> Both shirts are blue.

or

> Shirt A *and* Shirt B are blue

if you really need to reference each item.

This is more obvious where the colours are different.  It is really awkward trying to work something like:

> The colour of Shirt A is green and the colour of Shirt B is blue.

or worse:

> The colours of the shirts are: Shirt A is green and Shirt B is blue.

But at least they're grammatically correct.  The following (which is an inversion of the example sentences) **is not**:

> The colours of Shirt A is green and Shirt B is blue

Comment: I cannot think of a case where I would say "the color of something"; maybe I would use it to put emphasis on _color_, but in that case I would say "The color is blue." probably because somebody misunderstood what was blue.

Answer (score 0):

The prepositional phrase *of shirt-A and shirt-B* does not change the state of singular or plural, so

> The color is blue.

is the same as

> The color of shirt-A and shirt-B is blue.

and is correct.

> The colors of shirt-A and shirt-B are blue.

would be OK, but you need more than one color (you wouldn't say *the colors are blue*). So this would be OK

> The colors of shirt-A and shirt-B are blue and black.

In your last line, *both* doesn't add anything as I read it. *shirt-A and shirt-B* and *both shirt-A and shirt-B*  mean both shirts. The second example would be correct.